# How can i create click function between A1 to A10 prompt inputbox for user to enter numbers in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create input box for selecting range (A1 to A10), every time when i click any cells between 1 to 10, i want to prompt input box to enter numbers. That's what i did but it's not working properly, any suggestion..Also i have my code under THISWORKBOOK instead module1.

```
Function Find_Blank_Row() As Double

     Dim QtyInput As Double
     Dim BlankRow As Long
     BlankRow = Range("A10").End(xlUp).Row
     QtyInput = InputBox("Enter today expense")
     Cells(BlankRow, 1).Font.Bold = True
     Cells(BlankRow, 1).Value = QtyInput
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

You must put your code in the proper sub. This time, you need to use the Sheet Selection Change event to have your code run each time the user clicks somewhere. You also want to make sure the code only runs if the user clicked inside the desired range.

Also, I think your code has several more errors, like not checking the user input to make sure they entered a number, or not properly finding the first empty cell, but you can figure those out yourself, or ask another question. I'm not sure what you need, so I won't try to solve those.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Dim QtyInput As Double
Dim BlankRow As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row < 11 Then

  BlankRow = Range("A11").End(xlUp).Row
  QtyInput = InputBox("Enter today expense")
  Cells(BlankRow, 1).Font.Bold = True
  Cells(BlankRow, 1).Value = QtyInput

End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```